# How to assign environment variables in .env file to $_ENV variable php

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

In laravel, the environment variables are stored in the .env file and later assigned to the $_ENV superglobal variable. What should I do if I want the same function (get the variables in the .env file). I tried researching but my efforts are in vain...

Comment: Do you mean you want the same function in your project (not built with Laravel)?

Comment: Yes I wish to not use Laravel but have  the simillar function

Comment: To me It's not so clear what you are looking for, can you try to explain better?

Comment: I mean I want to get the variables like `APP_NAME=project` in the .env file and assign it to example: `$_ENV['APP_NAME']='project'`

Comment: are you using laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this lib for that: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Comment: Is there any other way by not using the libraries?